# Efficient way to check if a ReadOnlyMemory<char> contains in a Hashset in C#

Tags: c#, memory, hashset, iequalitycomparer

I've been looking for some efficient and precise way to check if a `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` in C# contains in a `Hashset` of ReadOnlyMemory or any other collection.

I saw some suggestions to convert to string, but I'd highly like to avoid it to enhance memory-efficiency. The only other way that I've found is to write the custom `IEqualityComparer`, but I'm also wondering if anyone has discovered a better solution.

Comment: Why "Contains" is not good enough?  HashSet<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> b = new HashSet<ReadOnlyMemory<char>>();  b.Contains(a);

Comment: @DA: because that would not compare the content. So if you add two objects with the same values, `Contains` will return `false`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter HashSet<T> cannot contain two objects with the same values since they would have the same HashCode.  Just look at the documentation for the HashSet<T>.Add method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=net-8.0#system-collections-generic-hashset-1-add(-0)

Comment: @DaveBlack: Maybe I expressed myself misleadingly. The question is about a `HashSet<ReadOnlyMemory<char>>`. You could `Add` the same `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` value multiple times(if it's not the same instance), because `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` doesn't override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` or implement `IEqualityComparer<ReadOnlyMemory<char>>`. So `b.Contains(a)` also doesn't work if `b` and `a` are different instances with the same value. In other words: the hashset does not know how to compare two instances. That's what Charlieface solved in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You do indeed need a custom comparer. But don't `ToString` anything inside the comparer, that's inefficient.

Instead use `Equals` on `Span`s that you create from the `Memory`. Also you can use `string.GetHashCode` which has a `Span` parameter.

```cs
public class ReadOnlyMemoryCharComparer : IEqualityComparer<ReadOnlyMemory<char>>
{
    public static ReadOnlyMemoryCharComparer Instance { get; } = new();

    public bool Equals(ReadOnlyMemory<char> x, ReadOnlyMemory<char> y) =>
        x.Span.Equals(y.Span, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public int GetHashCode(ReadOnlyMemory<char> obj) =>
        string.GetHashCode(obj.Span, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

With the static `Instance` property, you also don't need to create it every time.

```cs
var set = new HashSet<ReadOnlyMemory<char>>(ReadOnlyMemoryCharComparer.Instance);
```